# When Intent is received in Xamarin, ensure that only one instance is running at any given time

Tags: android, kotlin, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The Xamarin App sends and receives requests to the "central microservice" every 5 seconds using a timer. We can do an "action" in two ways: using intent from another app or scanning a QR code from a web app. Our app sends a request to the "central microservice" when scanning a QR Code or receiving an Intent, and receives a request from the "central microservice" after "5" seconds.

When scanning a QR code, the "central microservice" sends a single request per call.
However, while using Intent from another app, you may receive an additional request.
Apps are executing in two instances on Intent.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I tried adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

In `MainActivity.cs`, I inserted `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask` and `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance`.

In **Another App** (the Intent comes from), I inserted `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG ACTIVITY REORDER TO FRONT)`.

Both Apps are still active (can be seen by minimizing the app). How can I ensure that only one instance of the app is running at any given time when the Intent is being received?

**AndroidManifest.xml** *(Of Xamarin App, where the Intent will be sent to)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="1.0.10" package="com.example.XamarinApp" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
  <application android:label="DemoApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon_white" android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupOnly="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance"></application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
</manifest>
```

**Android App** *(From where the Intent is being sent to Xamarin App)*

```
var appPackageName = "com.example.XamarinApp"
var appActivityName = "com.XamarinApp.activity"

val intent = Intent()
intent.action = appPackageName
intent.setClassName(appPackageName, appActivityName)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

var firstName = "Hello"
Var lastName = "World"

intent.putExtra("firstName", firstName)
intent.putExtra("lastName", lastName)

AndroidSDK().signup(
                this@MainActivity,
                firstName,
                lastName)
```

**Android SDK**

```
fun signup(
    activity: Activity,
    first_Name: String,
    last_Name: String
) {

if (checkXamarinApp(activity, appPackageName)) {
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = appPackageName
intent.setClassName(appPackageName, appActivityName)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

val firstName = first_Name
val lastName = last_Name

intent.putExtra("firstName", firstName)
intent.putExtra("lastName", lastName)
} else {
    redirectToPlayStore(activity)
}
```

**Intent Filters**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Diagram**
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post your manifest. I'm not a Xamarin developer so I'm not that familiar with the how the manifest is used/generated. I know that you can also set manifest parameters in code with some kinds of annotations. Basically I would like to know how the app is being launched by other apps (including QR code scanners). Are you using intent filters?

Comment: I updated the question. please have a look. Yes, I'm using Intent Filters to open app Xamarin App from another App.

Comment: You didn't show how you are using the Intent filters. Also, do you want to have the Xamarin app opening in the same task as the Android app? Or do you want the Xamarin app in a separate task? It seems to me that you need the Xamarin app running in its own task, unrelated to the Android app.

Comment: Done. I want the Xamarin App to open in Android App (just one instance of the Xamarin App is running)

Comment: Sorry, this still makes no sense. If the Xamarin app is launched in the same task as the Android app, and you scan a QR code, then that will cause a launch in another task, as it cannot route the `Intent` to the Xamarin app running in the Android app's task. Maybe you should draw a diagram of what you have and how it shoudl work.

Comment: Also, what happens when the QR code is scanned? What URL is launched?

Comment: QR code scanning doesn't require intent. It's just a simple QR Scanner in Xamarin App, to scan Web App.

Comment: Okay, I'll draw a diagram, maybe that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243489/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-karamazov).

Answer (score 0):

There are four modes for the `launchMode`. According to the description, if you wanna single instance, you could use `singleTask` and `singleInstance`.

When you do this across applications,  you could use `singleInstance`. It makes that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.

For more details, you could refer to the link below. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: How do you use this mode? Could you provide the details for me to reproduce?

Comment: Added `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance` in `MainActivity.cs`. And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I adding the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: I added them in Xamarin App (where the Intent will be received). Should I add them or do i need to add anything in Anther App (from where the Intent will be sent)?

Comment: I updated the Question, please have a look.

Comment: Once an Activity instance in this mode already exists in a stack, any application that activates the Activity will reuse the instance in the stack. The link below shows the samples between Browser and Alarm Clock applications with four launch modes. It would give a better explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626218/examples-for-android-launch-modes